# Piping credentails to git push

Tags: command-line, git, automation, authentication, pipe

Whenever I execute `git push`, I have to type my username and password at the prompt manually.
However, I want to automate this process.

So, I tried to pass the credentials to the command using piping:

`printf 'username\npassword' | git push`

but the prompt for username and password still don't go away!
Why is it not working?

**Note:**
I know that this can be done using:
`git push 'https://username:password@github.com/username/repo.git'`
but I'm interested in knowing what's wrong with the piping method?

---

Also, to confirm that this process works for other cases, I did an experiment.
I created a script `b.py`:

*`b.py`*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

username = input()
password = input()

log = open("log.txt", "w")
print(username + "\n" + password, file=log)
```

Then, I executed `printf 'abcd\nefgh' | ./b.py` in the terminal which did work as expected and resulted in the log file containing the username and password strings:

*`log.txt`*:

```
abcd
efgh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would only work in the case of sequential prompts that are the immediate part of the script  as per your example. However in the case of `git` your values are being passed to the process prior to any username / password prompt - probably while its doing everything (network, etc) before `GIT_ASKPASS` - For reference:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables

Comment: So, is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Not that I'm aware. Other than that the in-lined method you referenced where the credentials are part of the address. Also the other thing to bare in mind is git reliance on the transport used - since it does not manage that - so I'd imagine that there would also be separation there so piping would probably not be possible without resorting to additional hacks.

Answer (score 1):

## Preconditions

Some time ago GitHub stopped accepting passwords and asked users to create tokens instead. Of course, I couldn't remember the token, but I also didn't want to store it as plain text in `.git-credentials`. Moreover, I didn't want to pass it as argument (someone can read `/proc` or `.bash_history` and find it!). I wrote my simple encryptor to encrypt token with a password, but, just like you, failed to pipe decrypted token to `git` and found this question while searching for a solution. Unfortunately, I didn't find the answer here. However, I was lucky to find unrelated question which led me to the answer. And the answer is [script](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html).

## Solution

We can use `script` to create an automated session and pipe credentials to it. This is the script I've written for it:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Password: " -s password
echo
token=$(echo "$password" | decrypt_token) || exit $?
cmd="git push $@"
echo -e "username\n$token" | script -E never -c "$cmd" /dev/null
```

`-E never` indicates that I don't want my credentials to be echoed (printed in terminal).
I'm using `/dev/null` as a log file since I don't care about logging.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** `echo` is a built-in command in my shell, which means that it's safe to pass password and token as arguments to it. If it'd be external program, someone could read the arguments from `/proc`. I recommend you checking whether the command you use for piping is built into your shell. If you couldn't find a suitable built-in, use cat with heredoc:

```bash
token=$(
  (
  cat <<EOF
$password
EOF
  ) | decrypt_token
)
```

## Part 2

After copying my setup to different machine, I've got a strange error:

`fatal: could not read Password for 'https://username@github.com': Success`

I've checked that both `git` and `screen` are the same version as on original machine and failed to find the root cause. However, [this comment](https://github.com/git/git/blob/aa9166bcc0ba654fc21f198a30647ec087f733ed/t/t0300-credentials.sh#L348) *may* provide a tip:

`getpass() tries too hard to find the real terminal`

As a workaround, I've created a separate script for `GIT_ASKPASS` (and I feel like it's a cleaner solution).

This is the main script after changes:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if ! tty -s; then
  echo "Can't operate without tty."
  exit 1
fi

TTY=$(tty) GIT_USERNAME=username GIT_ASKPASS=~/git-creds git push $@
```

And this is `git-creds`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

if echo "$1" | grep -q '^Password'; then
  read -p "Password: " -s password < $TTY
  echo "$password" | decrypt_token
  # put a newline to separate prompt and output
  echo > $TTY
else
  echo "$GIT_USERNAME"
fi
```

It reads the password directly from your TTY and gives decrypted token to git. For username it just echoes GIT_USERNAME env var.

It's also possible to add these lines to `.bashrc` (or any alternative):

```bash
export TTY=$(tty)
export GIT_USERNAME=username
export GIT_ASKPASS=~/git-creds
```

And you won't need the wrapper for commands.